# How to start Ipython notebook nbserver when it is this blue?

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Below is an image of what I see in the terminal after running

```
ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

Never before have I seen this, so please help.  The configuration file for the notebooks is as followed:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/jack/certificates/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:412341839uw9qfjewf8qewunq8eu8nu0fqef'
c.NotebookApp.port = 1024
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.  It's strange that even after I have set the port to 1024, it uses port 8888 (see image).

[image: ipython notebook nbserver fail]

Answer (score 0):

try adding the flag `--no-browser` to get the logs. The configuration file seem to not work, which file did you edit (`.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py` instead of `.ipython/profile_nbserver/ipython_notebook_config.py`?) ? What you see is just an in-terminal browser like `links`.

Your IPython notebook has been started correctly, just open firefox or whatever to http(s)://:port/

Comment: I made some basic indentation errors in the config file, so the specified port and no-browser were ignored. It's sorted now.  Thanks.